# Pandas loc find user that has applied to 5 or more things

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know which users have a FullCategory of length greater than 5.

I currently have a data frame called users_df that looks like this

```
UserId  FullCategory
1       [1,2,3,4,5]
2       [1,2,,5]
3.      [1,4,5]
```

I am trying to do this.

```
users_df.loc[len(users_df.FullCategory) > 5, :]
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
users_df.loc[users_df.FullCategory.str.len() > 5]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm